# Is it always better practice to add classes to elements than styling them directly?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it better to hide an element by adding display: none; to the element using JS or is it better to add a class that has the attribute display: none;? I understand that adding a class is usually better than adding styles directly because it's easier to manage but if it's only one property is it okay to just add style directly?

Answer (score 1):

This really comes down to personal preference if we're talking about adding or removing a single style.

Personally, I prefer just adding/removing classes even for simple stuff like showing/hiding elements. The problem with inline styles is if you ever want to apply classes to the same element, the inline style will get precedence, which can cause some confusion and you're wondering why your newly added class's properties aren't applying.

The other benefit to applying classes for styling is you can easily add or remove properties in one place (the CSS) and you never have to update your Javascript (unless you make a new class and want to add/remove that also).